# ARToolKit5 camera not recognized

Tags: webcam, camera, gstreamer

Cheese recognizes my webcam. Output of `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`:

```
HD WebCam (usb-0000:00:14.0-7):
    /dev/video0
```

However, ARToolKit5 doesn't recognize the camera and outputs SMPTE color bars. Not sure if this is a GStreamer or ARToolKit thing. Output:

```
$ sudo ./simpleTest
Using video configuration ''.
Using default video config.
libARvideo: GStreamer 0.10.36
libARvideo: GStreamer pipeline is READY!
libARvideo: GStreamer negotiated 320x240@30.000fps
libARvideo: allocating 230400 bytes
libARvideo: GStreamer pipeline is PAUSED.
Image size (x,y) = (320,240)
*** Camera Parameter ***
--------------------------------------
SIZE = 320, 240
Distortion factor: k1=0.1147807688, k2=-0.5208189487, p1=-0.0002069871, p2=-0.0040593124
                  fx=337.085815, fy=316.949043, x0=159.148895, y0=118.950233, s=0.993923
339.14696 0.00000 159.14890 0.00000 
0.00000 318.88706 118.95023 0.00000 
0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 0.00000 
--------------------------------------
```

I've tried with [these strings](https://archive.artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=2_Configuration:config_video_capture) in the env variable `ARTOOLKIT5_VCONF`: `-device=LinuxV4L`, `-device=GStreamer`, `-device=Linux1394Cam`. Any help on how to get the camera to be recognized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinuxV4L2 is the correct device name, listed in the README but not in the online docs.

```
export ARTOOLKIT5_VCONF="-device=LinuxV4L2"
```